# Php: Float encoded in scientific notation with json_encode()

Tags: php, php-7.1

Using php7.1, this:

```
json_encode(['value' => 0.00001]);
```

would return this string:

> {"value":1.0e-5}

although I would like to get `{"value":0.0001}`

How can I achieve that?

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
json_encode(['value' => '0.00001']);
// returns {"value":"0.0001"}, not {"value":0.0001}

json_encode(['value' => '0.00001'], JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
// returns {"value":1.0e-5}
```

Comment: `JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING`

Comment: This also outputs `{"value":1.0e-5}`

Comment: [Not if your values was a string in the first place, as in the second part of your question](https://3v4l.org/Ia5Xt)

Comment: It's just not possible, unless you send it as a string.

Answer (score 1):

Line 4536 of PHP source code Zend/zend_strtod.c chooses E-style if you have more than 3 zeros (`decpt < -3`):

```
if ((decpt >= 0 && decpt > ndigit) || decpt < -3) { /* use E-style */
```